# tf.tape.gradient() returns None for certain losses

Tags: tensorflow, tensor

I am trying to figure out why sometimes `tf.GradientTape().gradient` returns `None`, so I used the below three loss functions(`mmd0()`, `mmd1()`, `mmd2()`), although the formats are a bit different for mmd0 and mmd1, the gradients are still returned, but for mmd2, the gradients are `None`. I print out the loss from those three function, does anyone why why it behaves like this?

```
def mmd0(x, y): # a and b are lists of aribiturary lengths
  return x  

def mmd1(x1, x2): # a and b are lists of aribiturary lengths
  dis = sum([x**2 for x in x1])/len(x1) - sum([x**2 for x in x2])/len(x2)
  return dis**2

def mmd2(x, y):
  dis = x-y
  return [tf.convert_to_tensor(elem) for elem in dis]

def get_MMD_norm(errors, sigma=0.1): 
  x2 = np.random.normal(0, sigma, len(errors))
  loss0 = mmd0(errors, x2)
  loss1 = mmd1(errors, x2)
  loss2 = mmd2(errors, x2)
  print("loss0:", loss0)
  print("loss1:", loss1)
  print("loss2:", loss2)
  return tf.cast(loss2, tf.float32)

def loss(model, x, y, sigma=0.1):
  y_ = model(x) # y_.shape is (batch_size, 3) for Iris dataset
  losses = []
  loss_object = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)
  for i in range(y.shape[0]):
    loss = loss_object(y_true=y[i], y_pred=y_[i])
    losses.append(loss) 
  batch_loss = get_MMD_norm(losses)
  single_losses_list = [loss.numpy() for loss in losses]
  return tf.convert_to_tensor(batch_loss, dtype=np.float32), single_losses_list

def grad(model, inputs, targets, sigma=0.1):
  with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    tape.watch(model.trainable_variables)
    batch_loss, single_losses = loss(model, inputs, targets, sigma=0.1)
  return tape.gradient(batch_loss, model.trainable_variables), batch_loss, single_losses 

grads, batch_loss, single_losses = grad(model, features, labels)
print("grads:", grads)
print("batch_loss:", batch_loss)
##########################################################
loss0: [<tf.Tensor: id=39621, shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=2.1656876>, <tf.Tensor: id=39659, shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=2.057112>, <tf.Tensor: id=39697, shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=2.2769136>, <tf.Tensor: id=39735, shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=2.0263004>, <tf.Tensor: id=39773, shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=2.1568372>, <tf.Tensor: id=39811, shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=0.7392154>, <tf.Tensor: id=39849, shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=0.7742219>, <tf.Tensor: id=39887, shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=2.2176154>, <tf.Tensor: id=39925, shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=1.0187237>, <tf.Tensor: id=39963, shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=2.160415>, <tf.Tensor: id=40001, shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=0.80997854>, <tf.Tensor: id=40039, shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=0.70803094>, <tf.Tensor: id=40077, shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=0.8207226>, <tf.Tensor: id=40115, shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=0.82957774>, <tf.Tensor: id=40153, shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=0.88732547>, <tf.Tensor: id=40191, shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=0.90633464>, <tf.Tensor: id=40229, shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=0.7932346>, <tf.Tensor: id=40267, shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=2.1767666>, <tf.Tensor: id=40305, shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=0.80166155>, <tf.Tensor: id=40343, shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=0.7831647>, <tf.Tensor: id=40381, shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=0.77431095>, <tf.Tensor: id=40419, shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=0.82067406>, <tf.Tensor: id=40457, shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=0.74510425>, <tf.Tensor: id=40495, shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=2.1666338>, <tf.Tensor: id=40533, shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=0.7922478>, <tf.Tensor: id=40571, shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=0.73235756>, <tf.Tensor: id=40609, shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=2.1792874>, <tf.Tensor: id=40647, shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=0.919183>, <tf.Tensor: id=40685, shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=0.761979>, <tf.Tensor: id=40723, shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=2.1664479>, <tf.Tensor: id=40761, shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=0.77892226>, <tf.Tensor: id=40799, shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=0.99058735>]
loss1: tf.Tensor(4.158007, shape=(), dtype=float32)
loss2: [<tf.Tensor: id=40935, shape=(), dtype=float64, numpy=2.325676997771268>, <tf.Tensor: id=40936, shape=(), dtype=float64, numpy=1.9988182000798667>, <tf.Tensor: id=40937, shape=(), dtype=float64, numpy=2.303379813455908>, <tf.Tensor: id=40938, shape=(), dtype=float64, numpy=2.0615775258879356>, <tf.Tensor: id=40939, shape=(), dtype=float64, numpy=2.2949723624257774>, <tf.Tensor: id=40940, shape=(), dtype=float64, numpy=0.7019287657319235>, <tf.Tensor: id=40941, shape=(), dtype=float64, numpy=0.8522054859739794>, <tf.Tensor: id=40942, shape=(), dtype=float64, numpy=2.0819949907118125>, <tf.Tensor: id=40943, shape=(), dtype=float64, numpy=1.065878291073558>, <tf.Tensor: id=40944, shape=(), dtype=float64, numpy=2.1225998300026805>, <tf.Tensor: id=40945, shape=(), dtype=float64, numpy=0.9485520218242218>, <tf.Tensor: id=40946, shape=(), dtype=float64, numpy=0.7221746903906889>, <tf.Tensor: id=40947, shape=(), dtype=float64, numpy=0.9985009994522388>, <tf.Tensor: id=40948, shape=(), dtype=float64, numpy=0.9143119687525019>, <tf.Tensor: id=40949, shape=(), dtype=float64, numpy=0.9230117922853999>, <tf.Tensor: id=40950, shape=(), dtype=float64, numpy=1.0220225043292934>, <tf.Tensor: id=40951, shape=(), dtype=float64, numpy=0.8735972169951878>, <tf.Tensor: id=40952, shape=(), dtype=float64, numpy=2.1279260795512753>, <tf.Tensor: id=40953, shape=(), dtype=float64, numpy=0.9597649765787801>, <tf.Tensor: id=40954, shape=(), dtype=float64, numpy=0.8338326272407959>, <tf.Tensor: id=40955, shape=(), dtype=float64, numpy=0.6674084331022461>, <tf.Tensor: id=40956, shape=(), dtype=float64, numpy=0.8679296826013285>, <tf.Tensor: id=40957, shape=(), dtype=float64, numpy=0.8174893483228802>, <tf.Tensor: id=40958, shape=(), dtype=float64, numpy=2.212290299049252>, <tf.Tensor: id=40959, shape=(), dtype=float64, numpy=0.7304098620074719>, <tf.Tensor: id=40960, shape=(), dtype=float64, numpy=0.8463413221121661>, <tf.Tensor: id=40961, shape=(), dtype=float64, numpy=2.3081013094190443>, <tf.Tensor: id=40962, shape=(), dtype=float64, numpy=1.0314178020997722>, <tf.Tensor: id=40963, shape=(), dtype=float64, numpy=0.774951045805575>, <tf.Tensor: id=40964, shape=(), dtype=float64, numpy=2.127838465488091>, <tf.Tensor: id=40965, shape=(), dtype=float64, numpy=0.909498425717612>, <tf.Tensor: id=40966, shape=(), dtype=float64, numpy=1.0217239989370837>]
grads: [None, None, None, None, None, None]
batch_loss: tf.Tensor(
[2.325677   1.9988182  2.3033798  2.0615776  2.2949724  0.7019288
 0.8522055  2.081995   1.0658783  2.1225998  0.948552   0.7221747
 0.998501   0.91431195 0.9230118  1.0220225  0.8735972  2.127926
 0.95976496 0.8338326  0.6674084  0.8679297  0.8174893  2.2122903
 0.73040986 0.8463413  2.3081014  1.0314178  0.77495104 2.1278384
 0.90949845 1.021724  ], shape=(32,), dtype=float32)
```

Answer (score 6):

Have you seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56916313/tensorflow-2-0-doesnt-compute-the-gradient/56917148#56917148) answer?  I think I'm having a similar issue, and I believe that your might be related to mine. It has to do with the loss that is computed with a step somewhere in the process where the tensor of interest is "lost" from the start of the tape to the end. The referenced answer notes that the original poster had an area where a numpy array was returned instead of a tensorflow tensor, thus leading to the Gradient Tape failing to compute the gradient.

I could be wrong because I am nowhere near a tensorflow expert, but that is something I keep seeing popping up while searching for a solution to my similar issue.