# Tensorflow 2.0 doesn't compute the gradient

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, gradient-descent

I want to visualize the patterns that a given feature map in a CNN has learned (in this example I'm using vgg16). To do so I create a random image, feed through the network up to the desired convolutional layer, choose the feature map and find the gradients with the respect to the input. The idea is to change the input in such a way that will maximize the activation of the desired feature map. Using tensorflow 2.0 I have a GradientTape that follows the function and then computes the gradient, however the gradient returns None, why is it unable to compute the gradient?

```
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.applications import vgg16

class maxFeatureMap():

    def __init__(self, model):

        self.model = model
        self.optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam()

    def getNumLayers(self, layer_name):

        for layer in self.model.layers:
            if layer.name == layer_name:
                weights = layer.get_weights()
                num = weights[1].shape[0]
        return ("There are {} feature maps in {}".format(num, layer_name))

    def getGradient(self, layer, feature_map):

        pic = vgg16.preprocess_input(np.random.uniform(size=(1,96,96,3))) ## Creates values between 0 and 1
        pic = tf.convert_to_tensor(pic)

        model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=self.model.inputs, 
                               outputs=self.model.layers[layer].output)
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            ## predicts the output of the model and only chooses the feature_map indicated
            predictions = model.predict(pic, steps=1)[0][:,:,feature_map]
            loss = tf.reduce_mean(predictions)
        print(loss)
        gradients = tape.gradient(loss, pic[0])
        print(gradients)
        self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, pic))

model = vgg16.VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=False)


x = maxFeatureMap(model)
x.getGradient(1, 24)
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is a common pitfall with `GradientTape`; the tape only traces tensors that are set to be "watched" and by default tapes will watch only trainable variables (meaning `tf.Variable` objects created with `trainable=True`). To watch the `pic` tensor, you should add `tape.watch(pic)` as the very first line inside the tape context.

Also, I'm not sure if the indexing (`pic[0]`) will work, so you might want to remove that -- since `pic` has just one entry in the first dimension it shouldn't matter anyway.

Furthermore, you cannot use `model.predict` because this returns a numpy array, which basically "destroys" the computation graph chain so gradients won't be backpropagated. You should simply use the model as a callable, i.e. `predictions = model(pic)`.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, however after editing the code, gradients still returns None, any other ideas why that might be?

Comment: Oh, I just realized one big oversight. It's about `model.predict`. I edited the answer.

Comment: @xdurch0 can you explain why you think indexing doesn't work (I am running to this issue in my own code). Here's more details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68614793/tf-gradienttape-returns-none-for-gradient. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Did you define your own loss function? Did you convert tensor to numpy in your loss function?

As a freshman, I also met the same problem:
When using tape.gradient(loss, variables), it turns out None because I convert tensor to numpy array in my own loss function. It seems to be a stupid but common mistake for freshman.

Comment: Hello there, welcome to Stack Overflow! How does this add/improve upon the accepted answer?

Answer (score 0):

FYI: When GradientTape is not working, there is a possibility of TensorFlow issue. Checking the TF github if the TF functions being used have known issues would be one of the problem determinations.

- [Gradients do not exist for variables after tf.concat(). #37726](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/37726).