# Tensorflow GradientTape computes only 'None' gradients with custom loss

Tags: python, tensorflow, gradienttape

So I have a model (A) that I´m training with a *custom training procedure*. It is supported by a second model (B). This means of course I have to use **tf.GradientTape** and compute + apply the gradients myself.

However, it doesn´t work as expected and instead as **gradients**, just a list [None, None ...] is returned. Code snippet:

```
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
  outputs = model(input_batch, training=True)  # output of model A
  critic_output = critic_model(outputs, training=True)  # output of model B
  loss = critic_loss(critic_output, 1)  # loss of model B with input generated by A
  model_grads = tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_variables)  # returns [None, ...]
```

The models are correct, I tested every aspect of them. This is not the first time I use Gradient tapes to compute gradients. However, here this time, instead of returning a list of tensors, the gradient call just returns a list of 'None's. I don´t know what´s going on.

I also looked into this [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56916313/tensorflow-2-0-doesnt-compute-the-gradient/56917148) and added every variable to the gradient tape with .watch(), and it didn´t change anything.
All other gradients are computed without problems. I tried pretty much everything and am desperate for help.

Comment: I wonder...   since the "loss" is based on "critic_output", maybe you have to add "critic_model.trainable_variables" to the "tape.gradient" call?

Comment: What @MarkLavin said. Maybe even replace model.trainable_variables with critic_model.trainable_variables? Alternatively, and this is just a guess, you could try training the models under separate GradientTapes?