# Tensorflow error where tf gradient returns list of None types

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, tensorflow2.0, gradient, gradienttape

I am running into a problem I have seen a few times online, e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56916313/tensorflow-2-0-doesnt-compute-the-gradient/56917148?newreg=f6413e3c914e4e5989fd1831a36ca8e1), but cannot pinpoint the issue in my case. The error is that, from a custom loss function, loss_tape1.gradient is returning a list of None and I am not sure why.

I split loss_gradient into two modes since I am dealing with two neural networks. mode == 2 works just fine but mode == 1 breaks.

```
  def loss_gradient(self, mode):
    loss_fn = Loss(N1 = self.N1, N2 = self.N2, d = d)

    if mode == 2:

      with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as loss_tape2:
        loss = loss_fn.total_N2_criterion(self.w, self.eta, self.w_terminal, self.eta_terminal, self.w_initial, self.eta_initial, self.W1, self.W2, self.W3)
      l_grad = loss_tape2.gradient(loss, self.N2.trainable_variables)

    else:

      with tf.GradientTape(persistent = True) as loss_tape1:
        loss = loss_fn.total_N1_criterion(self.w, self.eta, self.W4)
      l_grad = loss_tape1.gradient(loss, self.N1.trainable_variables)

    return loss, l_grad
```

The function total_N1_criterion is given by the following functions:

```
  def total_N1_criterion(self, w, eta, W4):

    N1_output = self.N1(w,eta)
    N2_output = self.N2(w,eta)
    N2_time_derivative = self.derivatives(w,eta)
    unreduced_loss = self.loss_term_4_prime(W4, w, N2_time_derivative, N1_output, N2_output)
    loss = tf.reduce_mean(unreduced_loss)

    return loss
```

```
  def loss_term_4_prime(self, W4, w, N2_time_derivative, N1_output, N2_output):
    product = tf.linalg.matvec(N1_output, N2_output)

    s = tf.zeros_like(w)

    for k in range(d):
      r = tf.multiply(N2_time_derivative[:,k], w)
      r -= product[:,k]
      s += tf.math.abs(r)

    return W4 * tf.math.square(s)
```

```
  def derivatives(self, w, eta):

    with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as tape:
      tape.watch(w)
      V = self.N2(w,eta)
      # print(V.shape, 'v shape')
    N2_time_derivative = tf.reduce_sum(tape.jacobian(V,w), axis=2) # jacobian?
    # print(N2_time_derivative.shape, 'mod deriv shape')

    self.N2_time_derivative = N2_time_derivative
    # print(f'time derivative shape: {N2_time_derivative.shape}')

    return N2_time_derivative
```

I tried to resolve the issue by viewing other Nonetype errors with the tf.gradient. Prior posts resolved the error by avoiding a conversion to numpy. However I don't see that being a problem here. I apologize for the weird names in the code. I am solving a math problem.